# Call action based on redux props received from another action

Tags: reactjs, redux

This sounds a little odd (I'm new to react/redux) but let's say I have a component in which I call an action like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getTask(this.props.match.params.id);
}
```

This action called here populates the redux state with some data related to the task (title, description etc.) What it also has is an id of another element which I need in order to call another action like so:

```
this.props.getSomethingElse(this.props.task.something._id);
```

The problem:
In `componentDidMount` I call the first action and I want to call the second action after I received the data from the first one because as I mentioned I need that id. How should I approach this? What's the best practice in this case?

EDIT: Redux action below.

```
//GET Task
export const getTask = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setTaskLoading());
  axios
    .get(`/api/tasks/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TASK,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TASK,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: You should add the getTask code as well.

Comment: Can we assume `getTask` is an asynchronous action?

Comment: getTask is a redux action fired when the componentmounts. It just populates the redux state with the task data. I added the code above.

Comment: Maybe I was not being clear explaining this. I call that getTask which gives me data in the redux state. Data (in this case the id) which I want to use in the second redux action call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React components should not orchestrate multiple redux calls. Calls should be dispatched because of user interaction, or life cycle (mount/unmount).

If you have actions that are dependent on other actions, you can combine them using a middleware (thunk for example) or sagas.

In this case, since `getTask` is a thunk, you can use it to dispatch multiple actions that can use the data returned from the async (axios) request:

```
//GET Task
export const getTask = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setTaskLoading());
  axios
    .get(`/api/tasks/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TASK,
        payload: res.data
      });

      // getSomethingElse
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SOMETHING_ELSE,
        payload: res.data.something.id
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TASK,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: I thought about this but I wasn't sure if it was the correct approach. Thanks for your answer!